# Cassandra multiple writes distribution

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I have a 3 nodes Cassandra (2.0.3) cluster installed
here's my table:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    id text,
    phone text,
    name text,
    email text,
    PRIMARY KEY (phone, id)
);
```

I use the datastax java driver

here's my user object creation:

```
User user = new User();
user.setId(UUIDs.timeBased().toString());
user.setEmail(null);
user.setName("test-user");
user.setPhone(Credential.MD5.digest("user-" + i));
```

I create 10k of these - i is the index of the user in my users array.
I do not want to use a batch insert, but rather simulate a stress of inserting multiple records.
Here's my code:

```
Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
            .addContactPoints(CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_ADDRESSES)
            .build();
final Session session = cluster.connect(keyspaceName);
final ThreadPoolExecutor tpe = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
for (final User user : users) {
    tpe.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            PreparedStatement ps = 
                session.prepare("INSERT INTO user (id, phone, name, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
            BoundStatement bs = new BoundStatement(ps);
            bs.bind(
                    user.getId(),
                    user.getPhone(),
                    user.getName(),
                    user.getEmail(),
            );

            session.executeAsync(bs);
        }
    });
}

tpe.shutdown();
tpe.awaitTermination...
```

1. when counting the number of records (using cqlsh) I never get beyond a 4k (out of 10k)
2. only a single server is doing the writes (using opscenter write-request/all-nodes graph) - I can't see the reason: keys are random enough as far as I can tell...

Can someone point me anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

> when counting the number of records (using cqlsh) I never get beyond a 4k (out of 10k)

You are using an unbound thread pool, this means all writes are nearly executed at the same time. Probably you reached a performance limit and Cassandra answers with write timeouts. Try to reduce the number of concurrent writes and check the result of the execution.
E.g.

```
final ThreadPoolExecutor tpe = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);    
...
ResultSetFuture future = session.executeAsync(bs);
try {
    future.getUninterruptibly();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

> only a single server is doing the writes (using opscenter write-request/all-nodes graph) - I can't see the reason: keys are random enough as far as I can tell...

The primary is defined as `PRIMARY KEY (phone, id)`. This means `phone` is the partition key, and `id` is only the clustering key. But if the phone values are really different MD5 digests, this should spread across all nodes.

Comment: Martin, regarding the second part of your answer, I know it should spread correctly. I know that the tokens are good from the opscenter ring view and still only one node is doing the writes.